# How to create an XSD type which accepts a series of predefined values?

Tags: xml, types, xsd

I am trying to define a type to use in my XML document where it only accepts for that specific datatype, one of the following values:

- Product1
- Product2
- Product3

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found the answer using the attribute "enumeration". [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp) is the explanation, and the following code is the example used in it:

```
<xs:element name="car">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Audi"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Golf"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="BMW"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Was just about to post approximately this, but as you got there yourself first, have an upvote.